# How do I make the button output what it's supposed to? The button is supposed to create an average and then output it in text but it will not do this

Tags: html

```html
<!doctype html>


<html>

<head>
  <title> Grade Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2> Grade Calculator</h2>
  <p>
    Enter your Lab Grade: <input type="text" id="labBox" size=10 value=""> <br><br> Enter your Homework Grade: <input type="text" id="homeworkBox" size=10 value=""><br><br> Enter your Midterm Grade: <input type="text" id="midtermBox" size=10 value=""><br><br>    Enter your Final Grade: <input type="text" id="finalBox" size=10 value=""><br><br>
    <br>



  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Average" onclick="lab=parseFloat(document.getElementById('labBox').value);
    homework=parseFloat(document.getElementById('homeworkBox').value);
    midterm=parseFloat(document.getElementById('midtermBox').value);
    final=parseFloat(document.getElementById('finalBox').value);
    grade=(homework+lab+midterm+final)/4;
    document.getElementById ('outputDiv').innerHTML='The average grade is '+ grade';">
  <br>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

the two lines above the final br are waht is causing the issue I think, it's supposed to output a value accompanied by "the average grade is" but the button doesn't actually do anything when clicked.

Comment: First of all, please avoid the inline event handlers. Instead, try to use `addEventListener`. Your code is not working because of some typoes, first, you used a double quote in `getElementById ("outputDiv")` it will break the whole `onclick`, and second, it is an unnecessary space in it and the third one is another unnecessary single quote at the end of `onclick` handler.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the double quote but it still won't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example of your current code with respect to my comment:

Your code is not working because of some typoes, first, you used a double quote in getElementById ("outputDiv") it will break the whole `onclick`, and second, it is an unnecessary space in it and the third one is another unnecessary single quote at the end of `onclick` handler.

```html
<!doctype html>


<html>

<head>
  <title> Grade Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2> Grade Calculator</h2>
  <p>
    Enter your Lab Grade: <input type="text" id="labBox" size=10 value=""> <br><br> Enter your Homework Grade: <input type="text" id="homeworkBox" size=10 value=""><br><br> Enter your Midterm Grade: <input type="text" id="midtermBox" size=10 value=""><br><br>    Enter your Final Grade: <input type="text" id="finalBox" size=10 value=""><br><br>
    <br>



  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Average" onclick="lab=parseFloat(document.getElementById('labBox').value);
homework=parseFloat(document.getElementById('homeworkBox').value);
midterm=parseFloat(document.getElementById('midtermBox').value);
final=parseFloat(document.getElementById('finalBox').value);
grade=(homework+lab+midterm+final)/4;
document.getElementById ('outputDiv').innerHTML='The average grade is '+ grade;">
  <br>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

But keep in mind the best way to write such a thing is to use [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in your javascript to stick with [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) solution and get the necessary elements once in your JS and then use them it on the click handler.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("input[type='button']");
const lab = document.getElementById('labBox');
const homework = document.getElementById('homeworkBox');
const midterm = document.getElementById('midtermBox');
const final = document.getElementById('finalBox');
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');

btn.addEventListener("click", average);

function average() {
  const grade = (parseFloat(homework.value) + parseFloat(lab.value) + parseFloat(midterm.value) + parseFloat(final.value)) / 4;
  outputDiv.textContent = 'The average grade is ' + grade;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Grade Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2> Grade Calculator</h2>
  <p>
    Enter your Lab Grade:
    <input type="text" id="labBox" size=10 value="">
    <br><br> Enter your Homework Grade:
    <input type="text" id="homeworkBox" size=10 value="">
    <br><br> Enter your Midterm Grade:
    <input type="text" id="midtermBox" size=10 value="">
    <br><br> Enter your Final Grade:
    <input type="text" id="finalBox" size=10 value=""><br><br>
    <br>
  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Average">
  <br>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```